# Java: How to change inproper shown characters in .properties files

Tags: encoding, intellij-idea, jira, language-packs

I have an existing JIRA language pack jar file and i want to customize its source code. How can i do it with the aid of IntelliJ Idea. I have the idea with JIRA plugin installed in it and i have installed atlassian SDK for plugin development.
What i have done so far:

I have imported the extracted jar file into IntelliJ idea. Language strings in *.properties files are not showing correctly. For example, *.properties files are showing like:

```
#Mon Jun 17 06:02:27 GMT 2013
admin.monitor.section=\u041D\u0430\u0431\u043B\u044E\u0434\u0435\u043D\u0438\u0435
admin.monitor.connection.pool=\u041F\u0443\u043B\u0421\u043E\u0435\u0434\u0438\u043D\u0435\u043D\u0438\u0439
admin.monitoring.section.desc=\u041C\u043E\u043D\u0438\u0442\u043E\u0440 \u043E\u043F\u0435\u0440\u0430\u0446\u0438\u0439 JIRA
admin.monitor.database.desc=\u042D\u0442\u0430 \u0441\u0442\u0440\u0430\u043D\u0438\u0446\u0430 \u043F\u043E\u0437\u0432\u043E\u043B\u044F\u0435\u0442 \u043D\u0430\u0431\u043B\u044E\u0434\u0430\u0442\u044C \u0438\u0441\u043F\u043E\u043B\u044C\u0437\u043E\u0432\u0430\u043D\u0438\u0435 \u043F\u043E\u0434\u043A\u043B\u044E\u0447\u0435\u043D\u0438\u0439 JIRA \u043A \u0431\u0430\u0437\u0435 \u0434\u0430\u043D\u043D\u044B\u0445. \u0412\u044B \u043C\u043E\u0436\u0435\u0442\u0435 \u0438\u0441\u043F\u043E\u043B\u044C\u0437\u043E\u0432\u0430\u0442\u044C \u044D\u0442\u0443 \u0438\u043D\u0444\u043E\u0440\u043C\u0430\u0446\u0438\u044E \u0434\u043B\u044F \u043D\u0430\u0441\u0442\u0440\u043E\u0439\u043A\u0438 \u043F\u0443\u043B\u0430 \u0441\u043E\u0435\u0434\u0438\u043D\u0435\u043D\u0438\u0439 JIRA \u0438 \u0434\u0438\u0430\u0433\u043D\u043E\u0441\u0442\u0438\u043A\u0438 \u043F\u0440\u043E\u0431\u043B\u0435\u043C \u043F\u0440\u043E\u0438\u0437\u0432\u043E\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043B\u044C\u043D\u043E\u0441\u0442\u0438. \u0421\u043C\u043E\u0442\u0440\u0438\u0442\u0435 {0} \u0434\u043B\u044F \u0434\u043E\u043F\u043E\u043B\u043D\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043B\u044C\u043D\u043E\u0439 \u0438\u043D\u0444\u043E\u0440\u043C\u0430\u0446\u0438\u0438.
admin.monitor.database.keywords=\u043F\u0443\u043B \u0441\u043E\u0435\u0434\u0438\u043D\u0435\u043D\u0438\u0439
admin.monitor.database.read.writes=\u0427\u0442\u0435\u043D\u0438\u0439 / \u0417\u0430\u043F\u0438\u0441\u0435\u0439
admin.monitor.database=\u041C\u043E\u043D\u0438\u0442\u043E\u0440\u0438\u043D\u0433 \u0411\u0430\u0437\u044B \u0414\u0430\u043D\u043D\u044B\u0445
```

What i have to do in order these files are opened properly? Please, any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make *.properties files to be shown properly open File menu and from there click settings. In Settings window, type File encodings. There is a checkbox called **Transparent native-to-ascii conversion**. Checking this checkbox solves all issues.